# tbb::concurrent_vector returns wrong size

Tags: c++, tbb, concurrent-vector

I've asked this question on a [TBB forum](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=81625), but I'm hoping someone here might have some additional thoughts.  I was debugging an issue we're seeing and noticed some strange behavior from `tbb::concurrent_vector`.

The bottom line is that after a `push_back()` call actually completes, the `size()` of the `concurrent_vector` does not reflect this.  I've narrowed it down to be capacity related because if I capture `capacity()` and `size()`, `size() == capacity() => true` which leads me to believe that `size()` is returning the capacity and not the actual number of elements.

I have created a simple program that duplicates this issue, which triggers most often when the vector is empty.  For simplicity, this program simply ASSERTs that `size() != 0` immediately after a `push_back()` call returns.  I hope someone can please tell me if this is expected behavior or if its a bug.

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <tbb/concurrent_vector.h>

typedef tbb::concurrent_vector<int> vec_type;

void invokePushBack(vec_type * vec)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i)
    {
        vec_type::iterator it = vec->push_back(1);
        assert(vec->size() != 0);
    }
}

int main()
{
    // note: the race condition doesn't always trigger,
    //       so we loop until it does.
    while(true)
    {
        vec_type vec;
        boost::thread_group tg;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i)
            tg.create_thread(boost::bind(invokePushBack, &vec));
        tg.join_all();
    }
}
```

According to their [reference manual](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/documentation.php):

> push_back() "Appends copy of value to
>   the end of the vector."

and

> size() returns "Number of elements in
>   the vector. The result may include
>   elements that are allocated but still
>   under construction by concurrent calls
>   to any of the growth methods (5.6.3)."

Based on this, I believe that `size()` should *at least* reflect the `push_back()` once `push_back()` returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue.  It turns out it is 'by-design' in `concurrent_vector`.  See [this link](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=81625&p=1#145217) for a forum response about it.