# concurrent_vector is not working inside parallel_for ( PPL )

Tags: c++, concurrency, parallel-processing, ppl, parallel.for

there is a sample working code below ( parallel_for using Parallel Pattern Library ( ppl ) ). The main problem in here is **sqr** < concurrent_vector > stored values changing in every execution, but it should not be!

I used < concurrent_vector > for random access why it's not working?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ppl.h>
#include <concurrent_vector.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace concurrency;

const int a = 10, b = 30;

critical_section cs;

int main() {

    concurrent_vector< int > labels( a * b );

    concurrent_vector< int > sqr( 5 );

    // filling label vector
    for ( int y = 0; y < b; y++ ) {
        for ( int x = 0; x < a; x++ ) {

            if( x<2 && y>3 )
                labels[ a * y + x ] = 1;
            else if( x<30 && y<5 )
                labels[ a * y + x ] = 2;
            else if( x>5 && y>10 )
                labels[ a * y + x ] = 3;
            else if( x>2 && y>20 )
                labels[ a * y + x ] = 4;
        }
    }

    // printing
    for ( int y = 0; y < b; y++ ) {
        for ( int x = 0; x < a; x++ ) {

            cout << labels[ a * y + x ] << ", ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    parallel_for ( 0, b, [ & ]( int y ) {
        for ( int x = 0; x < a; x++ ) {

            //cs.lock();  // when i used it's working but slow
            int i = labels[ a * y + x ];
            //cs.unlock();

            if ( i < 0 ) continue;

            sqr[ i ] ++;
        }
    } );

    for( int i=0; i<5; i++ )
        cout << sqr[i] << ", ";
    cout << "" << endl;

    system ("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "The parallel_for method does not guarantee any particular order of execution. Unlike a sequential loop, some higher-valued indices may be processed before some lower-valued indices." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg663527.aspx#sec2).

Comment: ok, but the end of all thread execution, the result must be same. Label's count ( 1, 2, 3 ) is not changing. What I missed or should before code to get correct result?

Comment: I guess, if using lock solves the problem, then you are wrong in this assumption.

Comment: you're correct locking is working, but it kills the parallelism for bigger array sizes. so, i am looking for another solutions or perspectives

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using `task_group::wait` method should be faster (as you don't have to lock/unlock every time) and it may work as you expect.

> This method blocks the current task until the tasks of another task
>   group have completed their work.

See MSDN: [Parallel Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg663529.aspx#sec3).

**Update:** I have run some timing tests and seems that this is not a solution (besides both fail on large data inputs on my Dual-Core). 
This can be a bug of "design' in concurrent_vector" as in Intel's TBB - [tbb::concurrent_vector returns wrong size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396598/tbbconcurrent-vector-returns-wrong-size)

Answer (score 2):

You aren't using any features of concurrent vector which are relevant to concurrency. In fact, you could replace it by standard vector with no difference... Apparently, the values of i overlap in each execution of the kernel. There is absolutely no guarantee that concurrent writes to the same element of the vector are synchronized. Therefore you're getting random results - it's just the consequence of data races on non-atomic writes.